# can i reduce even more the cpu clock for power saving?

Tags: linux, cpu-speed

I am using fedora 34 with gnome and the [cpufreq extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/) to control the execution speed of the cpu of a computer.

I have configured it to run in power saving mode, thus when doing nothing the cpu clock is about 600mhz when i configure the extension to use "1%" as minimum.

I would like to know if i can lower even more the cpu clock.
Is there any chance to meet undesirable bugs ?
Would this be more appropriate for even more power saving ?

Comment: What model CPU do you have (and what motherboard)? I posit that you cant go lower then 600 because thr CPU wont support it.   If you more power savings and hardware supports it, maybe you need to be looking at a lower-then-os level like undervolting and/or sleep states.

Comment: Why are you trying to "save power"?  Reduce heat generation?  Save on energy bill?  For the latter, proper PSU sizing is probably more important.

Comment: @sawdust `Reduce heat generation? Save on energy bill?` heat definitely. saving on energy bill is not bad either ; )

Comment: @davidgo It is `Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 `;

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202352/minimum-cpu-frequency-set-when-charging-and-battery-under-7 you should be able to set the frequency to 400Mhz on this cpu.  (No idea how accurate that is)

Comment: At the level of 400 or 600mhz, your power savings and additional heat disipation are going to be almost immeasurable, and I'd be surprised if you saved as much as $1 per year.

Comment: sure yes. I wanted to try to squash it some more.

Comment: someone left me a comment on june 11. I wished i knew who that was, at least to thanks him. About my decision, personal stuff. About the score, friend, does it matter ?